# React add event listener to certain part of div

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tooltip

Say I have a div that I want to close just by clicking the cross in the right hand corner. how would I do that with an event listener?

Do I attach the event listener to just that part of the div and then call my function that closes it?

I'm just react tooltip and I want to close the div `onclick` but only on a certain part of it

So far I have:

`<div ref={elem => this.myDiv = elem}> </div>`

`componentDidMount = () => { this.myDiv.addEventListener("enter", this.handleenter);}`

Comment: I would suggest.
1.create a child div inside the parent div
2. position the child where you would like to fire the click event
3. Add event listener to child div and close the parent div.

Comment: problem is I have the tooltip component as a child to my container component. so i need to pass the event listener down to the child and then pass something back up to the parent to change the props. seems a bit ugly :/